# Chargeback for hotel refund

Tags: refund

On 19.01. 2020, I have made a reservation at UK (Scotland) hotel. Booking made at that hotel could be cancelled any time (at least 1 day prior to check-in) with full refund.

On 25.03. 2020 I have sent an email asking for cancellation of my booking.

On 1.04.2020 I have received an answer stating that my booking has been cancelled, but because of COVID-19 situation, they have to „delay or defer“ refunds until they could better understand financial implications.

On 29.04. 2020 I have asked them for update regarding my refund.

Till this day, I have not received an answer from them and thus I would like to request a chargeback at my bank.
I understand that current situation is hard for many hotels, but I gave them 2 months already and I feel like Im being held responsible for government decisions to close hotels.

**Question 1**: Does this kind of issue even qualify for chargeback?

**Question 2**: My bank says that „Usually, a chargeback must be raised within 120 calendar days from the date of the transaction you're disputing, or from the agreed delivery date of your goods that never arrived.“  - I have made the booking more than 130 ago, but the cancellation was made only 60 days ago – which date is relevant? Can I still fit inside that „120 days“ limit?

**EDIT: Answers to questions in comments:**

I was supposed to be at hotel from 22.05. 2020 to 26.05. 2020. They charged me the day I made the booking - 19.01.2020

I am based in Czech Republic. I have used Debit card issued by Revolut (UK based company). I have paid from my Pounds account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made the reservation on 19 January to have a room for use starting on 22 May.

You cancelled on 25 March, well before deadline. Now on 29 May they still haven't paid you back.

Lets pretend there was no COVID-19 and you hadn't cancelled. If you had showed up on 22 May demanding the room, and they hadn't had one for you you would be able to disput the charge because they failed to deliver. The date in question to start the clock would be 22 May.

Now back to your case. When you cancelled on 25 March that would be when I would consider the clock starting. The failure was they didn't refund your money, so that is when the clock resets.

Regardless of the number of days your quote used the word "Usually". So that means that there are cases when they do allow charge backs for longer periods. I would have no problem demanding a charge back. Just give them all the dates when you submit the request.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer! I apprecciate your help :). One minor question: Do you think it is morally correct for me to ask for chargeback? I would love to give them more time, if I had at least some feedback from them about how is the situation developing, but all I get when I write them is automatic reply that they are closed and that emails will be checked periodically.

Comment: @JakubJ I don't see any moral problem with doing it. Would you choose to lend money unsecured and in practice interest-free to a business you hadn't booked with? If not there's no particular reason to treat this one differently especially as you've already given them quite a while. You also risk losing your money if they go out of business.

Comment: You are right, I tried to be reasonable enough with them and they had enough time to sort it out, no reason to wait any longer. Thank you .

Comment: @JakubJ The moral/ethical issue will (may) arise if at some point in the future you receive a refund from the hotel, after having done a charge-back and received that money. Shouldn't happen, but with the turmoil, it is not beyond the realm of possibility.